# How to keep the column left aligned in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file, in which i need to sequentially order one of the column. I have ordered the same but facing alignment problem with few of the rows. I am not getting how to keep the column aligned.

Following is my reference file where I am concentrating on only 6th column:

```
ATOM      1  CA  GLY P  12       9.393  37.464  31.388  0.00  0.00      P1    
ATOM      2  CA  SER P  13      12.158  39.603  32.954  0.00  0.00      P1
ATOM      3  CA  VAL P  52      41.104  47.186  31.473  0.00  0.00      P1    
ATOM      4  CA  GLN P 164      36.217  27.890  29.620  0.00  0.00      P1    
ATOM      5  CA  GLN P 165      34.809  29.586  32.649  0.00  0.00      P1    
ATOM      6  CA  GLY P  12      10.007  25.374  54.523  0.00  0.00      P2    
ATOM      7  CA  SER P  13      13.212  23.440  53.698  0.00  0.00      P2    
ATOM      8  CA  ASP P  14      16.884  24.084  54.463  0.00  0.00      P2
```

Following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open (DATA, "<try.pdb") or die "not";
open (FILE,">file.txt") or die "no";
my $n=11;
foreach my $line1 (<DATA>){

if ($line1 =~ m/^ATOM\s+\d+\s+[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+\s+P\s+(\d+)/){

$line1 =~ s/$1/$n/g;
print FILE $line1;
}
$n++;
}
```

Following is my output where alignment for 4th and 5th row got changed because in reference file there were three digit numbers.

```
ATOM      1  CA  GLY P  12       9.393  37.464  31.388  0.00  0.00      P1    
ATOM      2  CA  SER P  13      12.158  39.603  32.954  0.00  0.00      P1   
ATOM     41  CA  VAL P  14      41.104  47.186  31.473  0.00  0.00      P1    
ATOM    153  CA  GLN P 15      36.217  27.890  29.620  0.00  0.00      P1    
ATOM    154  CA  GLN P 16      34.809  29.586  32.649  0.00  0.00      P1    
ATOM    155  CA  GLY P  17      10.007  25.374  54.523  0.00  0.00      P2    
ATOM    156  CA  SER P  18      18.212  23.440  53.698  0.00  0.00      P2    
ATOM    157  CA  ASP P  19      16.884  24.084  54.463  0.00  0.00      P2
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two solutions to this - either [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to set field widths for printing or use `\t` :

```
$line1 = join ( "\t", split ( ' ', $line1 ) );
```

This splits it on any whitespace, and sticks it back together again with tab stops. Which should left align your columns again.

With `sprintf` you can specify a format, and allows you to configure e.g. leading zeros, number of decimals or just string alignment. I think it's perhaps a bit overkill for what you're doing though.

Comment: @Sorbique User input looks like PDB format. Mostly pdb files will not have whitespace in atom record. So better avoid using split with whitespace for PDB files.

Comment: @mkHun Huh? There's whitespace in the example data in the question.

Comment: @MattJacob There example data contain whitespace but most of the PDB files not have the whitespace for example `ATOM    188  O   HIS A  24      19.075  22.262  50.693  1.00108.06           O`  from this PDB file (http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/1mkh.pdb). So most of the bioinformatician uses `substr` for extract the data by the fixed offset and length by this PDB FORMAT (http://deposit.rcsb.org/adit/docs/pdb_atom_format.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your script.  First the space alignment with the 3 digit 6th column entries

Second the use of the g flag on the regexp which clobbers any other data that happens to be the same as the 6th column

The script below corrects these two problems.  The space alignment is overcome by matching on the whitespace and the digits in the 6th column and substituting in a even amount of whitespace.  This will work with $n up to 4 digits and assuming that the number in the 6 column does not occur before the 6th column.  If it does then the regexp will alter the first number.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open( DATA, "<try.pdb" ) or die "not";

#open (FILE,">file.txt") or die "no";
my $n = sprintf( "%4d", 98 );
foreach my $line1 (<DATA>) {

    if ( $line1 =~ m/^ATOM\s+\d+\s+[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+\s+P(\s+\d+)/ ) {

        $line1 =~ s/$1/ $n/;
        print $line1;
    }
    $n++;
    $n = sprintf( "%4d", $n );
}
```